# Returning a user with a list of the groups he belongs to in Django Rest API

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm writing an API and I want to return a list of users along with the groups each user belongs to. I'm fairly new to Django and I'm stuck. I've tried several ways but the closest I came to finding a solution is when Django returned auth.Group.none while the user is in a Group.

### authentication/models.py

```py
   class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
       role = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=120)
```

### authentication/views.py

```py
   class CustomUserView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsAdmin, ]
    serializer_class = CustomUserSerializer

    def get(self, request, format='json'):
        queryset = CustomUser.objects.all()
        serializer = CustomUserSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        filterset_fields = ['id', 'name', 'email', 'groups']
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

### authentication/serializers.py

```py
   class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.CharField(
        required=True
    )
    username = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(min_length=8, write_only=True)
    first_name = serializers.CharField()
    last_name = serializers.CharField()
    groups = serializers.CharField()
    role = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password', 'groups', 'role')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}
```

### JSON Output

```
    {
        "id": 4,
        "email": "",
        "username": "testuser",
        "first_name": "",
        "last_name": "",
        "groups": "auth.Group.None"
    }
```

Any input would be appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
groups = serializers.CharField()
```

, in your serializer is incorrect , change serializer to this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model= Group
        fields = ('id','name')

class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    username = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(min_length=8, write_only=True)
    first_name = serializers.CharField()
    last_name = serializers.CharField()
    groups = GroupSerializer(many=True)
    role = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password','groups', 'role')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Zahra Ebrahimi's answer is correct, Its just an extension of the answer.
if you want to use drf's browsable api form to create the instance, then add a `queryset` of `groups`, for the conveniences.

```
class GroupSerializer(PrimaryKeyRelatedField,serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model= Group
        fields = ('id','name')

class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ......
    ......
    groups = GroupSerializer(many=True, queryset=Groups.objects.all())
    ......

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password','groups', 'role')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}
```

Comment: Do I have to make a different serializer to save the user? When I make a post to the route and add a groupname it says 'list' object has no attribute 'name'

Comment: can you post a separate question regarding this and share the link here ?

Comment: @md-tanvir-raihan I created a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61658462/adding-a-user-to-a-group-django-rest-framework